# Error running C program compiled with Geany IDE Error Code: 127

Tags: 14.04, c, geany

I installed Geany IDE via Ubuntu Software Center. Wrote a hello world prog in C and it compiled successfully but when i tried to run it, it gave me this error:

```
./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./geany_run_script.sh: ./hello: not found

------------------
(program exited with code: 127)
Press return to continue
```

Could someone please tell me what i should do?

Comment: What flavor/desktop of Ubuntu are you running? there is a known issues with the KDM default terminal (konsole) in geany

Comment: i am running ubuntu 14.04 lts

Comment: me too...have the same problem..
I'm using ubuntu 14.04.1 (unity desktop)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only compiled your *source file*, but didn't build your *application*, meaning the linking was not done and the executable was not created. Use the "build" sub-menu from the "build" menu (default shortcut is F9 if I recall correctly) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Geany version from Ubuntu software center or Install a new version by removing the current one.
I was also facing the same problem then i tried this method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above and none worked for me. The easiest way is to add your program file path in **Edit > Preferences > General tab > Startup tab > Project Files** Save this.

Now, go to **Build > Set Build Commands > Execute Commands > Execute** add this as it is below: (don't miss the leading `.`)

```
."/%e"
```

Click OK. Now **Build > Build** (<kbd>F9</kbd>) and then **Build > Execute** (<kbd>F5</kbd>). Kaboom. Should work now.