# Geany error 127 when programming in C

Tags: ide, geany

[Error running C program compiled with Geany IDE Error Code: 127](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472760/error-running-c-program-compiled-with-geany-ide-error-code-127)

Hey, I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Geany 1.23.1. I also have build-essentials installed and working from Terminal, but when I try to run a C program with Geany, I get the exact same error as the person in the link above (Error code 127). Additionally, in the above question the Accepted answer states that to get rid of this error, you must Build your application. In Geany, I hit F8 to compile, then F9 to build, and finally F5 to run, but I get the following text in the terminal window:

```
./geany_run_script.sh: line 5: ./libfilesTest c: No such file or directory


------------------
(program exited with code: 127)
Press return to continue
```

I know that this question has been asked, but even though the asker of the above link I supplied said that the solution worked for him, it has not worked for me. So, please help me as much as you can to figure this pesky problem out. Thanks in advance, and ask if you need me to supply more info :)

Comment: Can you please go to Geany's `Build menu --> Set Build Commands` and check the contents of the `Execute` command?

Comment: "./%e c" here are its contents. the 'c' at the end is my own argument

Comment: Try putting the argument **outside** the quotes: `"./%e" c`

Comment: Check Edit>Preferences>General>Project files and check it is the same directory as your source file, if not change it and try again.

Comment: @steeldriver i did that and it worked. Thanks guys, its always the simple stuff that stumps me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your Geany `Execute` command. To run your program from Geany with an optional argument `c`, you should go to the `Build` menu, and under `Set Build Commands`, change

<kbd>Execute:</kbd> `"./%e c"`

to

<kbd>Execute:</kbd> `"./%e" c`